# Alternate approaches to querying big data from mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, redis, software-design

I have 7-8 tables in mysql database. All of these tables have billion records. Size of table ranges from 1GB to 5GB.

Issues:
1. SELECT query is slow. Takes 30 sec. to 1 min. for a complex SELECT query.
2. JOINS are extremely slow.

What are the alternative technologies which addresses this issue?

Sorry if my question seem naive. I have looked into Redis but it won't work since it is just a key/value store(joins can't be performed).

Comment: It's unusual to have 7-8 really big tables. More commonly, you would have one VAST table and 3 or 4 smaller tables.

Comment: I think we need some more details to help you with this case. Post here table and index structures and describe the problem field.

Comment: How can a 1GB table have 1 billions rows?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL can easily handle that volume of data.

If your query is slow, there are several more probable causes that are not related to the technology, such as schema design (the design of the database itself, normalization, data types, partitions), indexing and query design (using/joining only necessary tables/partitions, query using the correct index)